# python package cleanup

Tags: 18.04, python, pip

I have have been developing python without using virtual Environments and now I have a lot of python packages installed and installing a new package for one project breaks the dependency for another and debugging some environment installation is almost impossible.

I want to do some cleaning of the installed packages and start using environments for my projects. Something like this
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248073/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip)
but not for a virtual environment.

Now I know Ubuntu is is dependent on python, would this break my OS? If so how do I do it safely?

I am using python 3.6.9 that was installed by default.

All packages were installed using `pip3 install <package_name>` and no other python versions were installed.

I want to do it for 2 machines running Ubuntu 18.04 and lubuntu 18.04

Comment: Depends upon how you installed all those other versions of Python. Your link specifies `pip`, that person knew how they installed the software. Your question should specify if you know how you installed those other versions of Python (easy), or of you are seeking a way to discover all your installed versions of python regardless of source (harder).

Comment: Can you start over on a modern version of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or 22.04 LTS?

Comment: @mondotofu part of the reason I want to clean up is because I plan on upgrading, but before I do that I need to figure out exactly what libraries each of my projects use so that I can move them to environments without wasting time figuring out what used what, not all my projects have a requirements.txt or yaml ...etc file.

Comment: package managers are pretty good at figuring that out.  Anaconda is excellent for python packaging.